# Creating a JSON object in MonoTouch (C#)

Tags: json, c#-4.0, mono, xamarin.ios

How do i manually create a JSON object in monotouch(4.0)?

The System.JSON namespace is available, (`JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, `jSonPrimitive` and `JsonValue`) but those are all abstract, so i can't just do this :

```
JsonObject myObject = new JsonObject();
```

I need to manually build a JSON object, and do not want to use DataContractSerialisation.

For reference purposes :

-I will need to transfer that JSON object to a server with a web call later. (but i can handle that part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, after a long time of trying and searching ; only the `JsonPrimitive`constructor and the `JsonObject` constructor can be used.

`JsonPrimitive` and `JsonValue` can both be cast to `JsonValue`.

the `JsonObject` requires a `KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>`

if i define functions like this :

```
public static KeyValuePair<String, JsonValue>  IntRequired(string key, int val)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<String, JsonValue>(key, new JsonPrimitive(val));
}
```

i can create a json object like this :

```
JSonObject myObject = new JsonObject();
myObject.add(new IntRequired("id",1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON.net http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: while JSON.net is a great library, i'm afraid it's out of the question for this particular project. +1 (since i didn't mention i can't use it) anyway.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what's the restriction against JSON.net?

Comment: More than a few reports of JSON.net working fine in the simulator, but crashing immediately when run on a real device.
I currently have no way to test this (as apple still has to verify my developer licence) but i need to finish my product within a limited time frame, so to be safe, i'd rather avoid it.